# How to call a oracle stored procedure with RECORD as OUT parameter in JAVA or WSO2?

Tags: java, oracle, stored-procedures, jdbc, wso2

I have a oracle stored procedure as follows

```
create or replace PACKAGE MY_PACKAGE AS
  TYPE MY_RECORD IS RECORD
  (
    first_name abc.first_name%TYPE,
    middle_name abc.middle_name%TYPE,
    last_name abc.last_name%TYPE 
  );
  TYPE MY_RECORD_REF IS REF CURSOR RETURN MY_RECORD;
  PROCEDURE getDetails(
    roll_no IN OUT VARCHAR2,
    V_MY_RECORD_REF   OUT MY_RECORD_REF);
END MY_PACKAGE;
```

I want to call the stored procedure using Java or WSO2. How can I do it?

Please advice.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I included some useful links in my answer to your previous question.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. Works like charm :)